# Remove or Update 'Reply' button in Email Message Page layout

Tags: custom-button, button, emailmessage

When I click on 'Reply' button in Email Message record, it opens /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor page. Here, I want to populate cc field. I am able to do that in a custom button by sending the necessary details in query params like below.

```
emailUrl += '?p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}';
emailUrl += '&p4=' + encodeURIComponent(p4_lkidValue);
emailUrl += '&rtype=003';
emailUrl += '&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}';
emailUrl += '&retURL=/{!Case.Id}'

location.href = emailUrl;
```

This works perfectly fine.

I want to use the custom button in place of 'Reply' and for this I am trying to remove the 'Reply' button in Email Message page layout. I don't find an option in edit page layout to do so.

Other option I thought was to update the logic required in existing 'Reply' button but I can't do that either.

I realized that these are standard buttons and cannot be modified or updated. So, I created a new page layout which is blank layout, and yet I see these buttons.
[image: Screenshot blank page layout]

Any help or advise on this is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try under 'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions' on Email Message Pagelayout ?